# How to replace text in a contenteditable div?

Tags: javascript, html

After researching on the internet, I couldn't find an answer to fit my issue. So I have a contenteditable div and the replace method of a string does not work. So the idea is that I want to replace the subString with nothing (""). The subString is simply a phrase not the whole text in the div. But the replace method of the string does not do anything, and I tried debugging it but it was no luck. The newTask() creates another div inside this contenteditable div, so it may vary the outcome.

Here is the code:

```js
var bodyText = document.querySelector(".textarea");

bodyText.addEventListener("keypress", () => {
    var key = window.event.keyCode;
    if (key === 13) {
        var contenteditable = document.querySelector("[contenteditable]");
        var text = contenteditable.textContent;

        var subString = text.substring(
            text.indexOf("!") + 1,
            text.lastIndexOf("!")
        ); //gets specific phrase
        // 'subString' phrase is also the thing i wanted it to be replaced

        const string = subString;
        if (subString !== "") {
            console.log(string);
            newTask(string);
            text.replace(subString, "[][]"); //<--this does not work
        }

    }
});

function newTask(input) {
    var taskDiv = document.createElement("div");
    taskDiv.className = "task";
    taskDiv.addEventListener("click", () => {
        taskDiv.classList.toggle("completed");
    });

    var textboxDiv = document.createElement("div");
    textboxDiv.className = "textbox";
    textboxDiv.contentEditable = true;
    textboxDiv.innerHTML = input;

    taskDiv.appendChild(textboxDiv);
    bodyText.appendChild(taskDiv);
}
```

Ask me if you need anymore information. Thanks for thr help!

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't understand your question!

Comment: @MaikLowrey I simply want to change a specific phrase in a contenteditable text without messing up the formatting, etc.

Comment: Having experience much frustration in this same area, perhaps investigate the [getSelection() method ](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection) and [its properties and methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection).  A user can paste more than just text into a contenteditable division, things your code may not be expecting, and cause you problems. The methods are interesting but apparently not very reliable.  There must be a reason why SO uses textareas, here, instead of a contenteditable division as a rich text editor.

Comment: If you're objective is to modify the textContent only, using a textarea may be simpler and more reliable.  [setRangeText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/setRangeText) and [setSelectionRange()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/setSelectionRange) may be useful and also making use of regular expressions, especially the [exec()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) method. For me, it was challenging to learn, but once caught on, it was very useful.

Answer (score -1):

Try using below code

```
const newText=text.replace(subString, "[][]");
contenteditable.textContent=newText;
```

Comment: This works but messes up the formatting and blocks the newTask() from being able to run

Comment: What newTask does? Share it's code. There we need to add above code. Targeting new div

Comment: just added the code, thank you pointing it out

Comment: textboxDiv.innerHTML=input.replace(subString, "[][]");

Comment: No, it doesn't work, it replaces the text in the "task" instead of the first div....I think you might have gotten confused, but the function and the rest of the code are in different functions.....just updated the code, sorry for the confusion....

Comment: Do you want that replace text before new div which is created by newTask?

Comment: Yes, so when someone types in a specific phrase, that phrase (subString) should get deleted and the newTask should be added in the position of the phrase

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Why you want to replace  with [][].. How does it look like

Comment: Try adding my answer code before calling newTask()